# Java - Using HttpServletRequest objects in MVC patterened design

Tags: java, http, servlets, model-view-controller

I understand that using `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse`objects in an MVC-patterned web application has benefits e.g. interrogating HTTP request details and setting useful attributes for the view (e.g. JSPs) to use them. But is there any recommended practice for NOT using HttpServletRequest/Response objects in the design - and I mean in any specific places e.g.

1) Service Layer/DAO

2) Model

Recently I have had a code review from a peer who suggested that I should remove the usage of HttpServletRequest/Response objects from the service layer. Besides that fact that Service Layer is strictly for everyone to use (i.e. should not pass request/response objects like that), I cannot seem to see any other reason. Would anyone care to help and tick my brain?

KR,

Comment: Do you really need another reason? Passing HTTP related objects to layers that shouldn't know or care about HTTP at all is pretty bad design, affecting the testability and stability of your system.

Comment: it's not about another reason or no reason - HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse interfaces have been used by bespoke applications for a while and there's no harm in knowing where we should step back from using this in the design. I am happy to be shown a specific area where there are more evidences for/against it.

Comment: Well the question of good design vs. bad design is too broad for SO. You could post your code on codereview instead.

Comment: Backend shouldn't have any frontend-specific dependencies. Simple as that.